# Custom metadata from EFcontextprovider using POCO and ObjectCotext

Tags: c#, breeze, asp.net-web-api

I am new in breezejs and trying to develop an SPA with angular-breeze.
I have a class named POCOObjectContext which is inherited from the base class ObjectContext. My Database has a table named Customer and as well as I have a POCO named Customer. But I have some extra properties on the POCO Customer, like Email, SupplierName which are not the table columns. When I take the Metadat() from EFContextProvider it provides me only the columns which are in the table named Customer. But the context that holds the POCO named Customer, have all the properties i have declared. As a result in BreezeJS, while creating object from breeze.EntityManager, it is created according to the columns in the Customer Table, but i need these extra properties in the Metadata to get and save data from/to my database. Any help will be highly appreciated...

This is Context Class POCOObjectContext (tmpDataBaseEntities is ConnectionString)

```
    public class POCOObjectContext : ObjectContext
    {
      private ObjectSet<Customer> customers;

      public POCOObjectContext()
          : base("name=tmpDataBaseEntities", "tmpDataBaseEntities")
      {
          customers = CreateObjectSet<Customer>();              
      }

      public ObjectSet<Customer> Customers
      {
        get { return customers; }
      }
   }
```

This is POCO Customer which holds extra properties SupplierName and Email

```
    public class Customer
    {
      [Key]
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }
      public string SupplierID { get; set; }

      //Extra Properties not in the Customer Table as Columns
      public string SupplierName { get; set; }
      public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

Finally the Breeze Controller

```
    [BreezeController]
    public class ReceiveServiceController : ApiController
    {
        EFContextProvider<POCOObjectContext> _pocoContext = new EFContextProvider<POCOObjectContext>();

        ReceiveDal _rcvDal = new ReceiveDal();

        [HttpGet]
        public string Metadata()
        {
           var t = _pocoContext.Metadata();
           return t; // It holds the properties info that match with POCO and Database Table.
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, custom unmapped properties on the server are not included in the metadata definition sent to the client. You can, however, extend your client's Customer definition by doing something like this,

```
//Assuming you have camelCase naming convention enabled
function Customer() {
    this.supplierName = '';
    this.email = '';
}

entityManager.metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Customer', Customer);
```

Now when you call saveChanges, Breeze will include the above custom properties in the payload.

```
{"Id": 42, "Name": "Customer Name","__unmapped":{"supplierName":"Supplier Name", "email": "supplier@supplier.com"},...}
```

Then, on the server, you can examine and parse the JObject payload to retrieve the unmapped properties.

You can read more about extending Breeze entities on the client at http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Denisk for your response, I have already read the topic (Extending entities). It is good enough when the POCO (customer) is small. But in real business it has 8 to 10 properties like City, Country, CustomerCategory, CustomerType and many more which are referential to Customer table with respective IDs. So it becomes more tedious and as well as difficult to manage code by defining those properties in both js and c# end. In the case of getting data from BreezeControllerAPI to js I cant send data with the values of these fields, because the metadata is not prepared with these extra fields.

Comment: I see. Perhaps you can shed some light as to what the use case is for these extra unmapped fields? If you have many of them and they are critical for the business logic, why aren't you storing them in the db as well?

Comment: Yes You are right. All these field are stored in db. in CustomerTypeTable. which contains CustTypeID and CustTypeName columns. this CustTypeID is referential to Customer Table... So when I am going to view data I do an Inner Join between CustomerTypeTable and Customer, and In C# my Customer poco has two properties CustTypeID and CustTypeName to hold data with Customers, and no need to work with CustomerType poco. In this case EFContextProvider cant make metadata with this property CustTypeName in Customer poco. What I think I need metadata of my POCO rather than Table in objectcontext fashion.

Comment: Yes, as you mentioned, you can modify the metadata sent to the client by including those unmapped fields, although I don't have enough experience with this method to tell you whether it is maintainable or not. You might also consider redesigning your model and only include those unmapped fields that are truly required in the business context on the client.